# UrlLoader issue in actionscript3/flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http

I have some code that loads some data using UrlLoader from google, this code stopped working for google.com but stil works for other domains like google.co.uk , on google.com the loader.data is empty but if I load that url in the browser I can see the data so the server seems to respond. 
My question is how can I configure the UrlLoader so it will return the correct data.
Here is some test code,you can comment/uncomment the url to check the working url,any tips or sugesstions are welcomed thx.
Edit: this code is from Adobe AIR application that runs on desktop not inside a web browser.

```
public static function testPrediction():void{
        var _loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, err);
        _loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, err);
        _loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,err);
        _loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,err);
        _loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        //this does not work
        var url:String="http://www.google.com/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";

        //this link works
        //var url:String="http://www.google.co.uk/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";

        var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
        urlRequest.followRedirects=true;
        urlRequest.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0";

        _loader.load(urlRequest);
        function onComplete(e:Event):void{
            var loader:URLLoader=e.target as URLLoader;
            trace(loader.data);
        }
        function err(e:Event):void{
            trace(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's a hint: `http://www.google.com/crossdomain.xml`.

Comment: @MartyWallace Hi, I forgot to mention that the code runs in AIr on desktop and I get no security exception, if you stil think that you know the issue can you please add a response to this question with some details/references? Thx

Answer (score 0):

onComplete and err functgions are within body of testPrediction function - which may be causing unintended behaviour. Assuming this isnt a typo on your part, they should be outside of testPrediction:

```
public static function testPrediction():void{
    var _loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, err);
    _loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, err);
    _loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,err);
    _loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,err);
    _loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    //this does not work
    var url:String="http://www.google.com/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";
    //this link works
    //var url:String="http://www.google.co.uk/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";
    var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
    urlRequest.followRedirects=true;
    urlRequest.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0";
    _loader.load(urlRequest);
}

static function onComplete(e:Event):void{
    var loader:URLLoader=e.target as URLLoader;
    trace(loader.data);
}
static function err(e:Event):void{
    trace(e);
}
```

Edit:

This code works for me using either URL. I removed the HTTPStatusEvents (because i was testing a swf, not AIR) and removed the followRedirects and userAgent settings from URLRequest (as they dont exist):

```
function testPrediction():void
{
var _loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, err);
_loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, err);
_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
//var url:String = "http://www.google.com/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";
var url:String = "http://www.google.co.uk/complete/search?js=true&output=toolbar&hl=en&q=ubuntu";
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
_loader.load(urlRequest);
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
trace(loader.data);
}
function err(e:Event):void 
{
trace(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, is not that, I wrote it like this so it is easy for people here to just copy and paste it then run it. I tried you code too and is not working, this issue is http related, I think

Comment: So you get loader.data!="" ? I used same code as you and I still get an empty data with the first url

Comment: yes, same data for both urls - <?xml version="1.0"?><toplevel><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="ubuntu"/>... etc

Comment: that is strange because me and a lot of users have same issue, are you runing the code inside a browser? is is an AIr app can you export it as .fxp

Comment: yep, looks like my answer is scrap ;) i get same result as you when run as AIR app

Comment: maybe a clue? getting SecurityErrorEvent for both urls when run in browser